# High precision Discrete Fourier Transform in c

Tags: c, precision, fourier-transform

I'm trying to do a high precision discrete fourier transform on a signal. To examine the precision, I use a gaussian function as the signal, because the fourier transform is also a gaussian function. 
[image: fourier transform of gaussian function using Mathematica]

The code is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tgmath.h>

typedef long double complex cplx;
long double PI;
void _fft(cplx buf[], cplx out[], int n, int step)
{
if (step < n) {
    _fft(out, buf, n, step * 2);
    _fft(out + step, buf + step, n, step * 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 2 * step) {
        cplx t = cexpl(- I * PI * i / n) * out[i + step];
        buf[i / 2]     = out[i] + t;
        buf[(i + n)/2] = out[i] - t;
    }
}
}

void fft(cplx buf[], int n)
{
cplx out[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) out[i] = buf[i];

_fft(buf, out, n, 1);
}


int main()
{
const int nPoints = pow(2, 12);
PI = atan2(1, 1) * 4;
cplx dt = 1e-3;
cplx dOmega = 1 / (dt * nPoints);
long double T[nPoints];
long double DOmega[nPoints];

cplx At[nPoints];
cplx tau = 28.4e-3;
for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; ++i)
{
    T[i] = dt*(i-nPoints/2);
    DOmega[i] = dOmega * (i - nPoints / 2);
    At[i] = cexpl(-T[i]*T[i]/2/(tau*tau));
}

fft(At, nPoints);
FILE* fw;
fw = fopen("fft_01.txt", "w+");

for (int i = 0; i < nPoints; ++i)
{
    fprintf(fw, "%.15Le, %.15Le\n", DOmega[i], fabs(At[i]) );
}

return 0;
}
```

When I change the defined type from float complex to double complex, the result did show a improvement in precision. However, When I change the data type from double complex to long double complex, there's no improvement while the numbers are far away from the minimal limit.

[image: result with float data]
[image: result using double data]
[image: result using long double data]

I think that the two wings of the peak should go down like the results by Mathematica, but here it seems stuck around 10^(-35) and can not further get down.

When I further apply a iDFT to the result of DFT, it's more apparent that the long double precision has been lost. The blue one is the original signal, with high precision. The green one is the result after **iDFT(DFT(x))**, which should be coincide with the blue one, but the minimal numbers are much larger.
[image: result by iDFT(DFT(x))]

Anyone can tell me where is the problem, thanks in advance.

PS: I am on Mac OS 10.13.1, using `gcc` as the compiler.
I have checked the numerical limits on my platform

```
storage size for float: 4
minimum float positive value: 1.175494e-38
Maximum float positive value: 3.402823e+38
precision value: 6

storage size for double: 8
minimum double positive value: 2.225074e-308
Maximum double positive value: 1.797693e+308
precision value: 15

storage size for long double: 16
minimum long double positive value: 3.362103e-4932
Maximum long double positive value: 1.189731e+4932
precision value: 18
```

Comment: It is not clear what the question is.

Comment: The most common reason why long double might give the same answer as double is that there is somewhere a bug where a value is computed as double instead of long double, ruining the subsequent accuracy. I haven't tested this, but `PI = atan2(1, 1) * 4;` looks like it's always double. Try `M_PI`. Also, I agree with nicoguaro, the question could be a little easier to read if you made the actual question a bit more explicit.

Comment: @Kirill Actually, I have tried to use M_PI, but it seems less precise than this definition. My question is, the two sides should always get down to like 10^(-100) or 10^(-200) small, but now it seems limited to 10^(-35), which is only the precision by float.

Comment: @nicoguaro Thank you for your response. And I've updated the question. could you pls give me a hand

Comment: I thought you were asking why double results were the same as long double results, but I guess that's not it. What you're expecting is impossible due to roundoff errors. Also, I suspect M_PI might be double too, try `4*atan2(1.0l,1.0l)` to make sure, the long double answer doesn't look right because you'd expect the numbers to be smaller than for double.

Comment: Unfortunately, `4*atan2(1.0l,1.0l)` makes just the same as `M_PI`. And I think right now the result is at the bottom of float `(1e-38)` instead of double `(1e-308)`.

Comment: In addition to the atan2 call, all of the numerical constants (eg 4 in 4*atan2(1.0l,1.0l)) may be being cast to double.  When you compute npoints/2 this may be computed as a double and then cast to long double?

Comment: @Malcolm Thanks for your reply. However, I do not think the integer will affect the result, because c is naturally preserving the higher precision. Even they are being treated as long double, the long double nature of the output from DFT should not be degraded.

Comment: @RoyLiao Your results are consistent with accuracy being degraded in just such a way, and these bugs are always easy to miss. In fact, there exist compilers that treat `long double` as a synonym for `double`, so one really does need to carefully check everything.

Comment: You haven't told us what OS and compiler you're using.  This could be important.

Comment: @Kirill I have checked that the limit of `double` on my platform is `2.225074e-308`, and for `float` it's `1.175494e-38`. Even though it can not reach the limit for `long double`, I wonder why it is so far away from `double`?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I am on Mac OS 10.13.1, and using `gcc` as the default compiler. Thanks

Comment: @RoyLiao The limiting factor is not "the limit of `double`", but the accuracy with which operations are performed (machine precision), which is `2e-16` for doubles and `2e-34` for long doubles. You should probably stop and learn something more about floating point computations before you go on with your experiments, otherwise there are more suprises awaiting you.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks for your comment. And that means I can no longer get the exactly same signal even after IDFT followed by DFT, it that right? I know that the machine precision is far larger than the numeric limit, but I think `2e-16` is the value for epsilon(1). I do not know the difference, but in Matlab, epsilon(0) is much smaller than epsilon(1). Is the situation just the same here in C?

Comment: @RoyLiao Yes, Matlab and C use the exactly same IEEE standard floating point numbers. `2e-16` is important not because it is epsilon(1), but because it is the accuracy bound of operations (each operation is guaranteed to return a result within a relative error `2e-16` of the true result). DFT is a stable computation in norm, which means that it is going to return a result within a relative normwise error `2e-16` (times some factor that depends polynomially on the dimension) of the true result.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks again. And now I think you have made it all clear. I think I may try some other extended data type right? like the _float128 or such. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Comment: @RoyLiao If you need 300 digits of accuracy, your best bet is using a multiprecision library such as https://gmplib.org/.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I have tried several libraries to extend the precision. However, I found most of them do not support complex operations. I have tried `libquadmath`, `hpa`, `mapm`, `ttmath`, and `gmp` as well. Do you have some other suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RoyLiao I have never used it, but this one should work: http://www.multiprecision.org/index.php?prog=mpc If a slower interpreted language is OK for you, multiprecision complex numbers are implemented in Sagemath: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_numerical/sage/rings/complex_field.html. Also, you may find some useful pointers in this question https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23867/c-libraries-for-fast-fourier-transform-in-high-precision.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the various comments that point out that most built-in functions such as `atan` or `exp` operate on `double precision` variables, there is also the issue that `long double` on typical x86-type hardware is not actually much more accurate (if at all) than regular `double`. In particular, `long double` is not an *arbitrary precision* data type such as the ones that Mathematica uses -- Mathematica lets you choose the accuracy of variables however you want it, and it will compute things to this accuracy, but this is not the case for C's `long double` data type that has a fixed accuracy just like `double`.

Comment: Also, different compilers treat the long double type differently.  On some compilers, it's just a synonym for "double"  On others you will get the 80 bit extended precision type.  Also, the OS might turn on the double precision rounding mode by default.   You need to check your particular compiler and OS.  See http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/an_introduction_to_gcc/gccintro_70.html

Comment: @Wolfgang Bangerth, I have also tried the exactly double long complex functions for those functions used, like `cexpl`, `atan2l`, but it does not make much difference. And I think the problem is, why the result is far away from the double_limit, even using double data type.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I have checked the article you referred. Unfortunately, the problem does not lies here.

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference, or no difference at all? You cannot expect much more accuracy from 80-bit vs the usual 64-bit double precision.